# Docker SQL Server and .NET Core

Tags: .net, database, docker

How can I connect local docker SQL Server database to a .NET Core project?

My connection looks like:

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  shopapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}shopapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ShopApp/Dockerfile
      depends_on: db-server
      networks: localdev

db-server:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    container_name: WseiSQL
    environment:
        - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Kamil@Wsei
        - MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433
    ports:
        - "1400:1433"
    networks: localdev
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ComputerStore:ConnectionString"]));
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
}
```

and `appsettings.json`:

```
 "ComputerStore": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=db-server; Database=ComputerStore;User=sa;Password=Kamil@Wsei;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

[image: Docker SS:]

I have no idea how to connect my project to database, any advice?

Comment: Your docker-compose file says you are mapping port 1400 to port 1433 in your container. But you screenshot shows that you are trying to connect to the dB on port 1433 still.

Comment: You can try using server ip address like "Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=my_db;User=sa;Password=qwertY12@3;".

Comment: Seems all ok, try Server=db-server,1433 also make sure you create DB=my_db on the server before connecting

Answer (score 0):

If you have sql server installed locally, it is most likely already running on port 1433, so change the default host port in the docker container.

In your connection string, instead of

```
Server=db-server;...
```

put

```
Server=.;...
```

. means localhost
If you are specifying another port you can say

```
Server=.,<port>
```

Example connection string

```
Server=.,1400;Database=ComputerStore;User Id=sa;Password=Kamil@Wsei;Trust Server Certificate=True;
```